# How can Moody see through the Invisibility Cloak?

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

How can Mad-eEye Moody perceive Harry Potter through the Cloak of Invisibility when Xenophilius Lovegood says

> "endures eternally, giving constant and impenetrable concealment, no matter what spells are cast at it."?